# How to sync Google Account every one hour?

Tags: sync, samsung-galaxy-nexus

If I turn on sync of my Galaxy Nexus, it makes batter life short. But I need sync my Google Account. So is there a way I can sync automatically every one hour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches to accomplish this. Ready-to-use tools like [JuiceDefender](http://www.appbrain.com/app/JuiceDefender-battery-saver/com.latedroid.juicedefender) or [GreenPower](http://www.appbrain.com/app/GreenPower-Free-Battery-Saver/org.gpo.greenpower) "stutter" data (i.e. turn data & sync on only in certain intervals, as you requested). The same could be accomplished using an automation tool like [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) or [Llama](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Llama-Location-Profiles/com.kebab.Llama), which then could be used for other automation as well.

Apart from that, you might want to check *what* you've enabled to sync (see: *Settings→Account & Sync*). Maybe you don't need to sync all of that, so you can uncheck parts. I found that about have the stuff enabled there by default I didn't want or need. Less stuff to sync also means less power needed for the job. And bandwidth saved as a side-effect.

Comment: How can I do it using Tasker?

Comment: Creating a profile that fires time-based (every hour), and in the task 1) toggle sync on, 2) "Tasker Wait" for 5 minutes, 3) toggle sync off – for a starter :)